# SELECT with yb_hash_code() and DELETE in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

We have below schema in postgresql (yugabyte DB 2.8.3) using YSQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.table1
(
customer_id uuid NOT NULL ,
item_id uuid NOT NULL ,
kind character varying(100) NOT NULL ,
details character varying(100) NOT NULL ,
created_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
modified_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT table1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, kind, item_id)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS unique_item_id ON table1(item_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS unique_item ON table1(customer_id, kind) WHERE kind='NEW' OR kind='BACKUP';

CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS public.item_data
(
    item_id uuid NOT NULL,
    id2 integer NOT NULL,
    create_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    modified_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT item_data_pkey PRIMARY KEY (item_id, id2)
);
```

Goal:

Step 1) Select item_id’s from table1 WHERE modified_date < someDate

Step 2) DELETE FROM table item_data WHERE item_id = any of those item_id’s from step 1

Currently we use query

```sql
SELECT item_id FROM table1 WHERE modified_date < $1
```

Can the SELECT query apply `yb_hash_code(item_id)` with the SELECT query? Because `table1` is indexed on `item_id` ? to enhance the performance of the SELECT query

Currently we perform:

```sql
DELETE FROM item_data x WHERE x.item_id IN the listOfItemIds(provided in Step1 above).
```

With the given `listOfItemIds`, can we use `yb_hash_code(item_id)` to enhance performance of DELETE operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should work out. Something like:

```sql
SELECT item_id FROM item_data WHERE yb_hash_code(customer_id, kind, item_id) <= 128 AND yb_hash_code(customer_id, kind, item_id) >= 0 AND modified_date < x;
```

While you can combine the SELECT + DELETE in 1 query (like a subselect), this is probably better because it will result in smaller transactions.
Also, no need to use `yb_hash_code`. The db should be able to find the correct rows since you’re sending the columns that are used for partitioning.